# How can I carry out model simplification for a MCMCglmm?

Tags: r, mixed-models, mcmc

I have a mixed-effects model that I am running in the package MCMCglmm in R. There are several possible predictors that I am interested in exploring. **How can I carry out model simplification to exclude uninformative predictors from the model?**

In other contexts, I have used stepwise backwards regression i.e. starting with a "full" model which contains all of the predictors that I am interested in, and using `drop1()` to find uninformative variables, followed by `update()` to remove them from the model.

Neither of these functions appear to work with MCMCglmm objects. What is my best alternative? I guess that one reason that `drop1()` doesn't work is that the MCMCglmm object does not have an AIC value. Could the DIC value be used in a similar way instead? I don't know much about DIC values, but in the example below they don't seem to be behaving like AIC would: after removing a variable from the model, the DIC is reduced by over 100.

For `update()`, clearly it's possible to specify the model again from scratch, but it involves copy/pasting quite a long function call, and gets even more complex with longer model formulae that include interactions. I wondered if there is a simpler alternative.

I'm also wondering if there is a reason that there has not been a method written for these functions to work with MCMCglmm objects - is what I am trying to do in some way invalid?

Reproducible example using partially invented data:

```
set.seed(1234)
library(MCMCglmm)

data(bird.families) 
n <- Ntip(bird.families)

# Create some dummy variables
d <- data.frame(taxon = bird.families$tip.label, 
                X1 = rnorm(n),
                X2 = rnorm(n),
                X3 = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), n, replace = T),
                X4 = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), n, replace = T))

# Simulate a phenotype composed of phylogenetic, fixed and residual effects
d$phenotype <- rbv(bird.families, 1, nodes="TIPS") +
               d$X1*0.7 + 
               ifelse(d$X3 == "B", 0.5, 0) + 
               ifelse(d$X3 == "C", 0.8, 0) +
               rnorm(n, 0, 1)  

# Inverse matrix of shared phyloegnetic history
Ainv <- inverseA(bird.families)$Ainv

# Set priors
prior <- list(R = list(V = 1, nu = 0.002), 
              G = list(G1 = list(V = 1, nu = 0.002)))

# Run model
model <- MCMCglmm(phenotype ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4, 
                  random = ~taxon, 
                  ginverse = list(taxon=Ainv),
                  data = d, 
                  prior = prior, 
                  verbose = FALSE)

summary(model)

# drop1(model, test = "Chisq") # doesn't work
# update(model, ~.- X2)        # doesn't work

model2 <- MCMCglmm(phenotype ~ X1 + X3 + X4, 
                  random = ~taxon, 
                  ginverse = list(taxon=Ainv),
                  data = d, 
                  prior = prior, 
                  verbose = FALSE)

summary(model2)
```

Full model output:

```
 Iterations = 3001:12991
 Thinning interval  = 10
 Sample size  = 1000 

 DIC: 145.2228 

 G-structure:  ~taxon

      post.mean l-95% CI u-95% CI eff.samp
taxon     1.808   0.2167    3.347    17.88

 R-structure:  ~units

      post.mean  l-95% CI u-95% CI eff.samp
units    0.6712 0.0003382    1.585    20.98

 Location effects: phenotype ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 

             post.mean   l-95% CI   u-95% CI eff.samp  pMCMC    
(Intercept) -0.6005279 -1.5753606  0.2689091   1000.0  0.198    
X1           0.7506249  0.5220491  1.0033785    506.8 <0.001 ***
X2          -0.0339347 -0.2452923  0.2085228    900.7  0.712    
X3B          0.6276852  0.1238884  1.1727409   1000.0  0.022 *  
X3C          1.0533919  0.4244092  1.5095804   1000.0 <0.001 ***
X4B         -0.0002833 -0.5099753  0.5103896    478.3  0.978    
X4C          0.0723440 -0.4435520  0.6193011   1000.0  0.776    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Reduced model output:

```
 Iterations = 3001:12991
 Thinning interval  = 10
 Sample size  = 1000 

 DIC: 296.4755 

 G-structure:  ~taxon

      post.mean l-95% CI u-95% CI eff.samp
taxon     1.542  0.07175      3.1    26.33

 R-structure:  ~units

      post.mean  l-95% CI u-95% CI eff.samp
units    0.8155 0.0004526    1.661    21.89

 Location effects: phenotype ~ X1 + X3 + X4 

            post.mean  l-95% CI  u-95% CI eff.samp  pMCMC    
(Intercept) -0.606920 -1.380267  0.335225   1000.0  0.172    
X1           0.750929  0.540667  1.011041   1000.0 <0.001 ***
X3B          0.633123  0.149282  1.243790   1000.0  0.032 *  
X3C          1.047085  0.518664  1.570641   1000.0 <0.001 ***
X4B          0.007019 -0.528080  0.512161    509.2  0.998    
X4C          0.063093 -0.490103  0.590965   1000.0  0.818    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```